# C extension: <? and >? operators

Tags: c, gcc, max, min

I observed that there was at some point a `<?` and `>?` operator in GCC. How can I use these under GCC 4.5? Have they been removed, and if so, when?

```
Offset block_count = (cpfs->geo.block_size - block_offset) <? count;
cpfs.c:473: error: expected expression before ‘?’ token
```

Comment: Note that this question is specific to C.

Comment: Where's all the love coming from for this question? Thanks!

Comment: Coincidental resemblance to PHP short-form tags <? ... ?>

Comment: @smci, nope, it's `<?` and `>?`, not the same.

Comment: *"Note that this question is specific to C."* -- Note that it is actually specific to G++...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Recent manuals [say](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.1/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html):

> The G++ minimum and maximum operators (‘`<?`’ and ‘`>?`’) and their compound forms (‘`<?=`’) and ‘`>?=`’) have been deprecated and are now removed from G++. Code using these operators should be modified to use `std::min` and `std::max` instead.

A quick search of the past documents seems to indicate that they were removed around version 4.0 (3.4.6 includes them, 4.0.4 does not).

Comment: @Matt Joiner, That's what the docs say, yes: "GNU C++ (but not in GNU C)".

Comment: I'd like to give +1 if you can provide a link.

Comment: @Matt Joiner, SRSLY?  How about google?  Here:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/

Comment: Yeah... it's sad that it was removed. `a <?= b;` was a neat trick! Super concise and easy to read. Okay... `a = std::min(a, b);` is not that bad either. 8-)

Comment: That's not that sad, because one could spend looong time trying to understand what the hell this code is doing, if he hadn't known gnu extensions.

Comment: @CarlNorum: One should be citing with a link in the first place.

Comment: @cubuspl42 and searching for code containing `<?`, `>?`, `<?=`, and/or `>?=` on Google might be hard because Google doesn't always play well with symbols.

Comment: @AlexisWilke but I must admit, it does look a cool neat trick and I would definitely use it for the same purpose as OP if it wasn't replaced/deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

Earlier iterations of `g++` (*not* the C compiler) used these operators for giving you the minimum or maximum values but they've long been deprecated in favour of `std::min` and `std::max`.

Basically, they equated to (but *without* the possibility of double evaluation of `a` or `b`):

```
a <? b       -->       (a < b) ? a : b
a >? b       -->       (a > b) ? a : b
```

In terms of replacing them (and you really *should* replace them), you can use something like:

```
Offset block_count = cpfs->geo.block_size - block_offset;
if (block_count > count) block_count = count;
```

or equivalents using `std::min`.

I'm not a big fan of using C/C++ "extensions" (especially ones that have been deprecated and/or removed) since they tie me to a specific implementation of the language.

You should never use a non-standard extension where a perfectly adequate standard method is available.