# What is <?= in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C extension: <? and >? operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators)

Take a look at the top answer (by sclo) to problem D of this [Google Code Jam](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/scoreboard?c=32003#vf=1). It's C++ code, it must have compiled, and it contains statements such as this one:

```
double& ret = F[mask][cur][b];
if(j==cur) {
  ret<?=f(tmp,j,b||bad[i])+M[cur][i];   // WTF is <?=   ???
}
```

This doesn't compile in my Visual Studio 2008. What does the `<?=` mean?

Comment: Could it be C++0x code?! If it is, then it can't be compiled in VS2008.

Comment: I don't know, the file extensions is CPP. I've lost touch with the C++ language a few years ago.

Comment: Must be a typo, neither g++ or clang++ recognizes it.

Comment: My first hunch was that it would be a [digraph or trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs), however it doesn't look like any of the known sequences.

Comment: Wow, 10 votes for a duplicate question!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a gcc extension: [C extension: <? and >? operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators)

> Recent manuals [say](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.1/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html):
>
> > The G++ minimum and maximum operators (‘`<?`’ and ‘`>?`’) and their compound forms (‘`<?=`’) and ‘`>?=`’) have been deprecated and are now removed from G++. Code using these operators should be modified to use `std::min` and `std::max` instead...

Comment: +1: Removed from GCC around version 4 (from the answer on linked page).

Answer (score 3):

It's simply not valid C++. `<` Might be less than, an open angle bracket for a template argument list, or the start of a digraph however non of those can be followed by `?`, then `=`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a now deprecated g++ extension to the c++ language.

`a <? b` 
is the minimum, returning the smaller of the numeric values a and b;

`a >? b` 
is the maximum, returning the larger of the numeric values a and b.

There are also compound versions

`<?=`

and

`>?=`

that do assignment as well.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't compile also with GCC, and I've never heard of an operator `<?=`.

Anyway I would hazard a guess that `a<?=b` could have a semantics like: `a = (a<b) ? b : a`, but again, this is just a guess.