# Weird usage of conditional operator (>?=)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, conditional-statements

I was looking at some code and saw something like this:

```
int d = 1;
int somethingbigger = 2;

d >?= somethingbigger;

cout << d << endl;
```

I think this should output 2. But I can't even compile this with gcc 4.5.2.
The code was written in 2005 and compiled with gcc 3.4.4 (not 100% sure).

Can someone explain how this works and why I can't compile this with a recent compiler.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734396/what-is-in-c/4734502#4734502 which was closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the "maximum" assignment operator, [a GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_5.html#SEC107).

- If the extension is not enabled, then you will not be able to use this feature.
- [As of 4.0.1](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html):

  > **The G++ minimum and maximum operators** (`<?` and `>?`) **and their
  >   compound forms (`<?=`) and `>?=`) have been deprecated and will be
  >   removed in a future version**. Code using these operators should be
  >   modified to use std::min and std::max instead.
- It looks like [they were gone by 4.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators/3437425#3437425).

Comment: what the ***** is this *****???

Comment: Oh sorry, I was just astonished at the existence of something like this in GCC. Nice answer. :) +1

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well it doesn't any more :P

Answer (score 5):

That's not C++ code.

It's using a gnu-only extension, and is completely non-portable.

Just replace it with standard-compliant code:

```
if (d < somethingbigger) d = somethingbigger;
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, this is the shorter version of d = max(d, somethingBigger); or

```
d = (d < somethingbigger) ? somethingbigger : d;
```

Haven't seen this in a while though and I'm pretty sure thats a GNU extension to GCC.