# what is meant by this ....time1 >? = time2 in C++

Tags: c++

just came through a statement in 
this is the code,,

what exactly does this line mean..?   **timeO >?= timeB;**

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int tt = 0;

    int T; scanf("%d",&T); while (T--) {tt++;

        int N; scanf("%d",&N);

        int posO = 1, timeO = 0;

        int posB = 1, timeB = 0;

        char type[2]; int M;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {

            scanf("%s %d",type,&M);

            if (type[0]=='O') {

                timeO += abs(M-posO);

                timeO >?= timeB;

                timeO++;

                posO = M;

            } else {

                timeB += abs(M-posB);

                timeB >?= timeO;

                timeB++;

                posB = M;                

            }

        }

        printf("Case #%d: %d\n",tt,max(timeO,timeB));

    }

}
```

Comment: It compiles... http://codepad.org/c4T00MyB

Comment: Hmm I think this is a ternary conditional, assign if greater than. I'm going to Google a bit harder and figure it out.

Comment: This is not standard C++. Who knows what codepad is doing with it? Probably using the same non-standard GNU extension that the anony is doing.

Comment: Well from observation, it's "assign if greater than" http://codepad.org/hHNP10rr

Comment: @todda.speot.is hey thanks for the link....got it now :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird usage of conditional operator (>?=)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974373/weird-usage-of-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 2):

It's an old GCC extension [Minimum and Maximum Operators in C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_5.html#SEC107).

(Doesn't build with GCC 4.5 or above.)

Don't use it, it's not portable at all.

Comment: is there any better alternative to this...?

Comment: Yes, `std::min` and `std::max`.

Answer (score 0):

the point is you should convert it to second then  the answer is clear

```
int time1  = ((h1*60)*60)+(m1*60)+s1;
int time2  = ((h2*60)*60)+(m2*60)+s2;
    int result = time2-time1;
```