# Operator <?= in C/C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C extension: <? and >? operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators)
>   [What does the >?= operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean)

I was googling some C++ codes on the internet and just found this:

```
num <?= num2-num3+num4;
```

Does anyone knows what this operator stands for? I googled for it but found anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C extension: <? and >? operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators) and [What does the >?= operator mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean)

Comment: and people mock MSVC for not following standards and adding extensions :D

Answer (score 5):

It was a GCC extension at some point, now removed. It is the assignment version of `<?` which was simply the minimum operator. So that code reads "set `num` to `num2-num3+num4` if that is smaller than `num`". In standard C++:

```
num = std::min(num, num2-num3+num4);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a gcc extension, basically means

```
num = std::min(num, rhs);
```