# C++ Notation : "<?"

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C extension: <? and >? operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators)

I've been having trouble deciphering some C++ code and haven't been able to find anything through search.  Can anyone help me out with the code below using the '< ?' notation?

```
int maximumLength(int countA, int countB, int maxA, int maxB) { 
    long long ca=countA,cb=countB,ma=maxA,mb=maxB; 
    if(ma==0) ca=0; 
    if(mb==0) cb=0; 
    long long res=ca+cb; 


    // any help on the below two lines is appreciated!
    res<?=(cb+1)*ma+cb;
    res<?=(ca+1)*mb+ca;

    return (int)(res); 
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a digraph of some sort, but a quick search doesn't turn up anything.