# <?= operator C++ greater less question mark equals sign

Tags: c++, overloading, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I saw <?= and >?= used in a code:
http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_solution&rm=151152&rd=5854&pm=2923&cr=310333

I tried to compile without the includes to test if it's standard, but it didn't work. I then added the includes, but it still gives the same error:

> question-mark.cpp:15:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘?’
>   token question-mark.cpp:15:6: error: expected primary-expression
>   before ‘=’ token question-mark.cpp:15:9: error: expected ‘:’ before
>   ‘;’ token question-mark.cpp:15:9: error: expected primary-expression
>   before ‘;’ token

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int x = 3;
    int y = 2;
    x >?= y;
    printf("x = %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's how it is used in the code from the link:

```
x <?= h[i][j];  // x = (h[i][j] < x) ? h[i][j] : x;
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the >?= operator mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean)

Comment: Please choose a best answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are GCC extensions operators. `a <?= b` has the same meaning as `a = min(a, b)` (`>?=` is the "max" operator), but it evaluates its left-hand side expression only once. This is not important when `a` is a variable, but it may make a difference when `a` represents an expression, especially when the expression has a side effect. For example, in

```
*dest++ <?= *src++;
```

the `++` in `dest++` would be evaluated only once.

Both operators have now been [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437425/335858).

Comment: I'm not sure it's exactly the same, since the `<?=` operator only seems to evaluate `a` once (e.g. consider `f() <?= g()`).

Answer (score 3):

It's a GCC extension. `x >?= y` is equivalent to:

```
x = max(x, y);
```

I haven't seen it used in a while though.

Comment: Surely that should be `x = max(x, y)`?

Comment: @tacp: They're mentioned [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html#Deprecated-Features), but just to say that they've been removed.