# error: expected primary-expression before ‘?’ token C++

Tags: c++, gcc, operators, xerces

I am working on a project to extract meta-data from a document. Regarding that I came to know about [this Project](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/rbg/code/toc/), which is a method for the automatic generation of a table-of-contents, it made me install [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) (this installed fine). In the Read-Me.text of the Project it gave a warning as follows( I use Ubuntu14.04 and have `gcc 4.8.2`):

> It has been tested with gcc 3.3.5 on Debian, but should work with gcc 3.3.5 on other operating systems. Newer versions of gcc might give you a few easily corrected warnings / errors during compilation.  Despite this, functionality of the code is independent of both OS & compiler version.

When I tried to build the project, I was successful in correcting some warnings and errors, but there was this error I couldn't fix

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘?’ token
    iMaxSiblingMatches = iMaxSiblingMatches <? iSiblingMatches;
```

Here,
`iMaxSiblingMatches` and `iSiblingMatches` are both `int` data types.

I haven't seen this operator before and the compiler is also not able to identify it, is there something I am missing here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators. The >? and <? operators have been apparently removed.

Comment: If you start a line with four spaces, you can add code. See my edit