# Compile Error in compiling mysql 4.0.26

Tags: c++, mysql, gcc, compiler-errors

For some reason I need to use mysql 4.0.26 on linux.
I can't find it on mysql.com, but finally I found it on a ftp server.
while I do "make" in terminal, there was an error.

```
In file included from client_priv.h:19:0,
             from mysql.cc:32:
mysql.cc: In function 'void print_table_data(MYSQL_RES*)':
./../include/my_global.h:352:25: error: expected primary-expression before '?' token
#define max(a, b) ((a) >? (b))
                        ^
```

I am in ubuntu 16.04 and this is my gcc version:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C extension: <? and >? operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators)

Comment: I would not trust "some ftp server". You can get old releases [from github](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/releases/tag/mysql-4.0.26). And if you try to compile very old software with new compilers you will likely fail. Maybe gcc 4.x will work.